# how to create checkout table from cart foreach loop

Tags: php, cart, checkout

Am trying to create a checkout table with the following cart objects. If the cart page is loaded, I want all the cart objects inserted into the checkout table and if any of the products is already in the checkout table (probaly someone toggle between the cart page and shopping page) I want to update checkout page as show below.

I will be glad if I can be put through on this. Thanks

```
<?php
    foreach ($gs->getLists('cart') as $ps):
        $cart = $gs->getGoods($ps['p_id']);
        array_map(function($ps) {
            $pid = $ps['p_id'];
            $pu = $ps['pu'];
            $pn = $ps['pn'];
            $pp = $ps['pp'];
            $pk = $ps['pk'];
            $tp = $pp * $pk;

            if (!isset($_id)) {
                "INSERT INTO checkout (p_id, pu, pn, pp, pk, tp)
                VALUES ('$pid','$pu','$pn','$pp','$pk','$tp')";
            }else{
                "UPDATE checkout SET pk=:pk, tp=:tp WHERE p_id = 'p_id'";
            }
        }
    ?>
....some html

<?php
        }, $cart);
    endforeach;
?>
```

The database connection as below

```
 public $kuo = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->kuo = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
        if($this->kuo->connect_error){
            echo "Fail" . $this->kuo->connect_error;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an error or something not working?

Comment: it is not workin. did not store anythin on the checkout table

Comment: What is $_id variable? Is it a mistake and should be $pid?

Comment: It's a typo error, it should be $p_id

Comment: $p_id doesn't exist. You should say $pid.  where do you execute your query?

Comment: by the way your update query is not valid

Comment: $pid or $p_id, still didn't work

Comment: You dont execute the query. With your code, it is a basic string. How do you connect to your database?

Comment: The database connection is shown.

Comment: Ok so as you use mysqli , you should use [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to execute your query